# Pandas Dataframe change column values with given interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert my columns values according to an interval like,

```
if(x<5)
  x=2
else if(x>=5 %% x<10)
  x=3
```

and try to doing in python with single line code. Using mask and cut method but I could not do.
this is my trial,

```
dataset['CURRENT_RATIO' ] = dataset['CURRENT_RATIO'].mask((dataset['CURRENT_RATIO'] < 0.02, -7.0) | (dataset['CURRENT_RATIO'] > =0.02 & dataset['CURRENT_RATIO'] < 0.37),-5))
```

I need this actually `if x<0.02 then -7 else if x>=0.02 and x<0.37 then -5...`

```
  inptut output
    0.015  -7
    0.02   -5
    0.37   -3
    0.75   1
```

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could share sample input with expected output.

Comment: Try [`pandas.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: Please explain the full problem. The solutions being provided are not meeting your needs as you have partial information in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

A list comprehension will do:

```py
dataset.CURRENT_RATIO = [-7 if i<.02 else -5 if i<.37 else -3 if i<.75 else 1 for i in dataset.CURRENT_RATIO]
```

Timing it with a random dataset of 1,000,000 rows gave the following result:

`334 ms ± 5.89 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

## Multiple Columns

If you were to do this with multiple columns with different thresholds and update values, I would do the following:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'RATIO1': np.random.rand(10000000),
                   'RATIO2': np.random.rand(10000000)})

update_per_col = {'RATIO1': [(.02, -7), (.37, -5), (.75, -3), 1],
                  'RATIO2': [(.12, 5), (.47, 6), (.85, 7), 8]}
cols_to_be_updated = ['RATIO1', 'RATIO1']

for col in cols_to_be_updated:
    df[col] = [update_per_col[col][0][1] if i<update_per_col[col][0][0] else 
               update_per_col[col][1][1] if i<update_per_col[col][1][0] else 
               update_per_col[col][2][1] if i<update_per_col[col][2][0] else update_per_col[col][3]
               for i in df[col]]
```

When we time the for loop with 10,000,000 rows and two columns we get:

`9.37 s ± 147 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

To address Joe Ferndz's comment, lets try to speed it up. I came up with two methods: `apply()` and a `lambda`. With `apply()` we run the following code (only the for loop was timed):

```py
def update_ratio(x, updates):
    if x < updates[0][0]:
        return updates[0][1]
    elif x < updates[1][0]:
        return updates[1][1]
    elif x < updates[2][0]:
        return updates[2][1]
    else:
        return updates[3]

for col in cols_to_be_updated:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(update_ratio, updates=update_per_col[col])
```

This gives us:

`11.8 s ± 285 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Finally the `lambda` gives:

```py
for col in cols_to_be_updated:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: update_per_col[col][0][1] if x<update_per_col[col][0][0] else 
              update_per_col[col][1][1] if x<update_per_col[col][1][0] else 
              update_per_col[col][2][1] if x<update_per_col[col][2][0] else 
              update_per_col[col][3])
```

`8.91 s ± 171 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

This means that a lambda is the fastest method, but a list comprehension is not far off.

Answer (score 0):

use

```py
dataset['CURRENT_RATIO'][dataset['CURRENT_RATIO']<10]=3
dataset['CURRENT_RATIO'][dataset['CURRENT_RATIO']<5]=2
```

first line you make all value less than 10 to 3
then all values less than 5 to 2
it makes all value between 5 to 10 remain 3

Comment: I can do it with multiple lines but I am searching for single line because I have 50 columns and each have six conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It would be smart to write your own `lambda`-function and use [`pandas.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
def my_lambda(x):
    if(x<5):
        x=2
    elif(x<10):
        x=3
    return x

dataset['CURRENT_RATIO' ] = dataset['CURRENT_RATIO'].apply(my_lambda)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have 50 columns and almost each have different conditon. So this solution requires lots of def.

Comment: This is something you did not mention in your question. Please provide an example.

Comment: In my question only for current_ratio column and for another column the intervals and values are different such as x<1000 then 5 else if x>1000 and x<10000 then 6